# MySQL - select as fiscal year

Tags: mysql, financial, leap-year, fiscal

I have this SELECT:

```
SELECT 
    m.`maschine-name` AS byMaschine,
    q.`mname` AS byMName,
    SUM(YEAR(q.`created`) = YEAR(CURDATE())) AS total
FROM qualitaet q INNER JOIN
    maschinen m 
    ON m.maschine = q.maschine
WHERE
    q.`status`='1'
GROUP BY
    q.maschine, q.mname;
```

to get all results for the current year and it looks like this:

```
| maschine-name | mname | total |
|     TYP 1     |   0   |   4   |
|     TYP 2     |   3   |   4   |
|     TYP 2     |   4   |   4   |
|     TYP 3     |   0   |   4   |
|     TYP 4     |   0   |   4   |
```

see **SQL Fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/aa307/1)**

**But i want to SELECT it as fiscal year (financial year) starting at >= Oct, 1 to get this result:**

```
| maschine-name | mname | total |
|     TYP 1     |   0   |   3   |
|     TYP 2     |   3   |   2   |
|     TYP 2     |   4   |   0   |
|     TYP 3     |   0   |   2   |
|     TYP 4     |   0   |   2   |
```

i have different Date statements which work all, but the fiscal year drives me crazy :-(

show data for **TODAY**:

```
SUM(DATE(created) = CURDATE()) AS total
```

show data for **CURRENT WEEK**:

```
SUM(YEARWEEK(q.`created`, 1) = YEARWEEK(CURRENT_DATE, 1)) AS total
```

show data for **CURRENT MONTH**:

```
SUM(q.`created` >= CURDATE() - INTERVAL DAY(CURDATE())-1 DAY) AS total
```

show data for **CURRENT YEAR**:

```
SUM(YEAR(q.`created`) = YEAR(CURDATE())) AS total
```

**Is there a way to get this result from above?**

Best regards and a happy new year ;-)

Comment: Just use the `DATE_ADD` or `DATE_SUB` to substract or add 10 months?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did it with MAKEDATE. Startdate is Oct, 1

```
SUM(q.`created` >= MAKEDATE(year(now()-interval 1 year),1) + interval 9 month) AS total
```

see SQLFiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/aa307/10)

complete SELECT:

```
SELECT 
    m.`maschine-name` AS byMaschine,
    q.`mname` AS byMName,
    SUM(q.`created` >= MAKEDATE(year(now()-interval 1 year),1) + interval 9 month) AS total
FROM qualitaet q INNER JOIN
    maschinen m 
    ON m.maschine = q.maschine
WHERE
    q.`status`='1'
GROUP BY
    q.maschine, q.mname;
```

Now i receive this result:

```
| maschine-name | mname | total |
|     TYP 1     |   0   |   3   |
|     TYP 2     |   3   |   2   |
|     TYP 2     |   4   |   0   |
|     TYP 3     |   0   |   2   |
|     TYP 4     |   0   |   2   |
```